# How to get model through many-to-many relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel, orm, model

I've got the following situation in Laravel, simply visualize by the following:

```
task -([many-to-many]- task_user -[many-to-many])- user -[one-to-one]- info
```

I'm able to get from task to user, but unfortunately I can not get to info.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm missing?

Model: task

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{

    public $table = "tasks";
    public function taskuser(){
         //task->task_user->user->info
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'task_user');
}
```

when I add ->belongsTo(Info::class) to the function taskuser I get the following error:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\RelationNotFoundException
Call to undefined relationship [taskuser] on model [App\Models\Task].
```

I'm definitely missing something but what?

EDIT: Info model works with user as User->info give the correct results
Model User:

```
public function info()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Info');
}
```

EDIT: Controller

```
$task= Task::whereBetween('datetime',array($start,$end))->with('tasktype','taskuser')->get();
```

EDIT: relevant tables

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();

    Schema::create('infos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned(); //internal id
        $table->string('name');  
        #foreign references
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');  

    Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('task_types_id')->unsigned();  
        $table->string('title');  
        $table->datetime('datetime');  
        $table->integer('length'); 
        $table->string('description')->nullable(); 
        $table->integer('updated_by')->unsigned(); 
        $table->timestamps();
        #foreign references
        $table->foreign('task_types_id')->references('id')->on('task_types');
        $table->foreign('updated_by')->references('id')->on('users');           

    Schema::create('task_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('task_id')->unsigned(); 
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned(); 
        #foreign references
        $table->foreign('task_id')->references('id')->on('tasks');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Comment: Can you change the name of that function `taskuser` to `mytaskuser` and check same error?

Comment: error is the same. Will edit with data from controller

Comment: Can you maybe show you the tables?

Comment: I have a task, task_user, user and info table

Comment: I mean can you actually show the columns instead of the table names

Answer (score 0):

By reading more of the Laravel documentation, specifically https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

adding **.info**

```
     $task= Task::whereBetween('datetime',array($start,$end))
     ->with('tasktype','taskuser.info')
     ->get();
```

Now it works.